# View on slave postgres database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

1. In postgres streaming replication master-slave setup, can we create views only on slave/standby server?
2. Can I have more than one standby slaves?

I am using postgresql 9.3.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re 1): this is not possible. The slave is always a **100% identical** copy of the master.

re 2): yes this is possible. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP):

> You can have any number of standby servers